# How to display a greater-than symbol at the start of a Slack attachment line with markdown enabled?

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to match a mock-up of a Slack API message that has a greater-than (>) character in a link at the start of an attachment text line.  The mock-up also uses italics and bold in the attachment text, so I have `text` in the `mrkdown_in` array.  Unfortunately, this causes Slack to interpret `&gt;` or `>` as a blockquote character when it occurs at the start of a line.  Does anyone know how to work around this?

I could use small greater-than (﹥) or full-width greater-than (＞), but it seems silly that I can't figure out how use the standard greater-than (>).

Here is a Slack sandbox message JSON that reproduces the problem I am having: [https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22...](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22_First%20line%20(needs%20to%20be%20italic)_%5Cn%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%7C%26gt%3B%20There%20should%20be%20a%20%5C%22%26gt%3B%5C%22%20at%20the%20start%20of%20this%20line%3E%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%5D%2C%22text%22%3A%22How%20do%20I%20display%20a%20greater-than%20character%20at%20the%20start%20of%20the%20link%20below%3F%22%7D)

Here is my JSON message from the above URL:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text": "_First line (needs to be italic)_\n<http://google.com|&gt; There should be a \"&gt;\" at the start of this line>",
            "mrkdwn_in": [ "text" ]
        }
    ],
    "text": "How do I display a greater-than character at the start of the link below?"
}
```

Here is how Slack renders my message, with some annotation from me in red:
 [annotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQcKa.png)

Comment: "funny" thing, &lt; works correctly. Gabriel, does it _need_ to be _that_ symbol?

Comment: Ideally it would look exactly like that character. But if that is actually impossible, then I will have to ask our client to go with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution is to enter a vertical tab (`\u000b`) before the greater-than-symbol. This apparently has the effect of escaping the greater-than symbol.
However, this does not work inside the link, so you have to move the vertical tab and the greater-than-symbol outside of it.

Example:

```
"text": "_First line (needs to be italic)_\n\u000b&gt;<http://google.com|There should be a \"&gt;\" at the start of this line>"
```

Full example here: [Message Builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22_First%20line%20(needs%20to%20be%20italic)_%5Cn%5Cu000b%26gt%3B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%7CThere%20should%20be%20a%20%5C%22%26gt%3B%5C%22%20at%20the%20start%20of%20this%20line%3E%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%5D%2C%22text%22%3A%22How%20do%20I%20display%20a%20greater-than%20character%20at%20the%20start%20of%20the%20link%20below%3F%22%7D)

Other "invisible" characters will work too. The question author found that `\u200a` (hair space) worked best for him.

I found the original solution for this problem on another Stack Exchange community: [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86557/how-do-i-escape-formatting-characters-in-slack)

Comment: @Gabriel Deal if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as solution, so we can close this question. Thank you!

Comment: Tricky!  Thanks.  Unfortunately, on my machines `\u000b` displays as a rectangle in Chrome on Linux & Windows.  Vertical tab looked fine on the other three browsers I tested it on.  But `\u200a` (hair space) looks good enough for me on every browser I tried.  Maybe update your answer to mention hair space too?

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I have added your solution to my answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: This seems to only work on OSX, I think it's a difference in the OS's general text display logic. Windows and various Linuxen all seem to display a rectangle.