# Is it possible to bold part of a word in Slack (Linux)?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to bold part of a word in Slack Chat. Example: Stack**Overflow**.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the Linux version of slack. Using message builder and unicode value \u000b does not seem to work (see image below).

[image]

Comment: Enclose within `Stack/*Overflow*`

Comment: Stack/*Overflow* results in an extra forward slash

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of OS or Browser,

You can it by using `＊`(FULLWIDTH ASTERISK `U+ff0a`) instead of `*` (normal asterisk).

Copy and paste the below into your slack channel to see it.

```
Stack＊Overflow＊ vs Stack*Overflow*
```

Or you can refer to [the Message Formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Stack%EF%BC%8AOverflow%EF%BC%8A%20vs%20Stack*Overflow*%22%7D)

[image]

Comment: are there different characters for `*bold*`, `_italic_` and `~strikethrough~`?

Answer (score 3):

The vertical tab character did not work for me, but using the [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)(\u200b) character and the [zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)(\u200d) did the trick.

By placing a zero-width space before the starting `*` and the zero-width joiner after it and the other way around for the ending `*`, slack correctly interprets the content between `*` as bold without introducing visible spaces. E.G.: `text<space>*<joiner>boldText<joiner>*<space>text`

You  don't actually need to place both of those characters nor do they have to be present both at the beginning and end. The space is necessary only if text is present right before the `*` (or after for the end `*`) and the joiner is needed if there is a space after the `*` (or before for the end `*`).

[Result of the message builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWmyW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a vertical tab in unicode (`\u000b`). It will not be displayed, but works to enable bold marking of the second part of the word.

[Example with message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22I%20am%20a%20test%20message%3A%20Stack%5Cu000b*Overflow*%22%7D)

Result with Message Builder:

[image]

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331295/how-to-display-a-greater-than-symbol-at-the-start-of-a-slack-attachment-line-wit/46342556#46342556).

Comment: Using unicode characters (\u000b) doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Have you checked the message builder example? It proves that it works. So if it does not work for you its likely that there is another complication. Please post your relevant code in the question. Then people might be able to help you with your specific issue.

Comment: Looking at the message builder I see: Stack▯Overflow. I am using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It works for me on Firefox / Windows 10. I added an image as proof. Apparently it behaves differently on Chrome and/or Ubuntu

Comment: I have added a picture of message builder using the suggested unicode character.